# How can I avoid damage from Sniper's Ultimate?

Tags: dota-2

What are the ways we can avoid getting hit by Sniper's Ultimate ability, Assassinate? Which items and/or hero abilities can be used to escape it once it has locked on to a hero?

Comment: Could you be more explicit ? What do you mean by "special" ? and what do you mean by "escape" ?

Comment: Posted an answer with wiki link with more detailled way to evade projectile

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There're several ways to do this, most require low ping & fast reflexes:

### By Disjointing

In DotA, [disjointing](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Disjoint) consist in removing oneself from being the target of a projectile. This can be achieved in several ways :

- By blink dodging if you blink as soon as it hits / split second
  before. This works with Queen of Pain, Anti Mage, Blink Dagger,
  Slark's Pounce, Mirana's Leap, Puck's Etheral Jaunt, Storm's Ball
  Lightning or Morphling's waveform, Nature's Prophet Teleportation.
- By creating illusions : With Manta Style you get a brief period of invulnerability when you use it, CK's Phantasm will give you 0.5s, Naga Siren's Mirror Image will give you 0.3s.
- By Banishing yourself : Lifestealer's infest or Puck's Phase Shift
- By Transforming yourself : Abilities that morph your hero grant some tiny frames of invulnerability so if timed well you can transform disjoint with : Chemical Rage (Alchemist), True Form (Lone Druid) and Metamorphosis (Terrorblade)
- Becoming invisible will disjoint projectiles **but not Assassinate** (since Assassinate gives true sight of the target)

### Blocking the damage

- With a skill like : Ember Spirit's Flame Guard (up to 500), Abaddon's Ultimate (Borrowed Time), Abaddon's Apotic Shield or Templar Assassin's Refraction.
- With an item : Like [Pipe of Insight](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Pipe).
- By becoming [magic imune](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Magic_immunity) : Black King Bar, OmniKnight's Repel, LifeStealer's Rage.

### By Becoming invulnerable :

[Invulnerability](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Invulnerability) is granted by several skills (and Eul's Scepter) in the game. You can become invulnerable by

- Being disabled : Using Eul's Scepter on yourself, same goes if you get Nightmared by Bane, Slept by Song onf the Siren, Disrupted (Shadow demon) or Astrast Emprisonned by Outworld Devourer etc (full list on the link).
- Being hidden : During Juggernaught Ultimate, or Ember's Sleight of Fist, Lifestealer's 
  infest or Phoenix's Supernova(full list on the link).
- Some blink grant invulnerability : Void's Timewalk or Tuskar's Snowball (for example).

### By Blocking the Spell completely

If you have a [Linken's Sphere](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Linken%27s_Sphere) or an ally uses his to buff you, the spell will completely be cancelled.

Note that all these also apply to most single-target spells

Comment: and if you are using bottle?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean, but it will cancel your heal if you're currently using a bottle. If you've almost got enough hp to survive, you may get enough from your bottle. But it should be a general rule that if you have bottle charges and are escaping low health you should use them asap.

Comment: i mean if am using bottle and sniper's ultimate hit me i get damage ?

Comment: Blink or any disjointing ability. Becoming magic immune in any way works.Primal Split, Supernova, Euls, Astrals emprisonements, and disruption falls under the same category : becoming invulnerable (along with a lot of other spells like nightmare or Song of the Siren). You can dodge by creating illusions with Naga and Chaos Knight aswell.

Comment: I edited your post so it's exhaustive and sorted by category. Hope you dont mind :). I will have to test X marks the spot and glimps because i think it doesnt disjoint

Comment: I am pretty sure that x marks the spot disjoins. (At least in HoN it does 100%).

Comment: @WizLiz In the future, if you have this much to add to an answer, please consider making your own answer instead. Then you'll also get the rep for it :)

Comment: @StrixVaria In normal time that's what i would have done but given that the answer was already accepted and asked by a relativéy new user, I assumed that the chance of the answer being unaccepted and mine accepted instead were low and i decided to edit the accepted answer to make it exhaustive. I don't know if its the right behaviour though.

Comment: Noteworthy: [You can disjoint Sniper's Assassinate by using Smoke of Deceit](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Sniper#Assassinate).

Answer (score 5):

Sniper's ultimate Assassinate is single target magic damage. Anything that blocks single target spells or makes you immune to magic damage will prevent it and it's damage can be reduced through magic resist such as cloak, hood, or pipe. The projectile, while fast, can be disjointed. Sniper can also be interrupted as it's a channeling ability prior to firing.

The request for specific hero abilities who can avoid it is somewhat unreasonable because there are so many. Look at the heroes you like to play and dig into their abilities. Anything that allows for disjoints (blinks, tornadoes, removals, invulnerabilities, slark's ult) can dodge the in air bullet with timing.

The quick list of items that can help you with the damage is: Hood, Pipe, Linkens, Euls, BKB, TP, Manta, Blink, Bloodstone, and finally if you're losing stack bracers.

Answer (score 2):

You can :

- [Disjoint](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Disjoint) the projectile (Except by becoming ivisible since Assassinate gives true sight of the target)
- Become [Invulnerable](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Invulnerability)
- Become [Magic Immune](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Magic_immunity)
- Block damage with spells such as : Apotic shield (Abaddon), Ember Spirit's FlameGuard, or Templar Assassin's Reflection or an item like [Pipe](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Pipe)
- Block the spell with [Linken's Sphere](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Linken%27s_Sphere)

Comment: The answer with all information you have was already posted 1 day [before](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/158636/74453). Why do you post it again?

Comment: @MikroDel If you watch carefully, the current accepted answer was not exhaustive and I edited it to make it complete but I edited it after I posted my answer. I figured after posting that editing the currently accepted answer would be more helpful

Comment: Thank you for your response on my comment. After the information you have given - the original answer of "Shane IvoKid Reid" was changed completely with your edits. Its not what the edits should do.

Comment: @MikroDel Yes i agree but the answer was accepted in a state that I concidered incomplete and wrong for some information. For the sake of the quality of the content of Arqade, I felt it was more right to edit the accepted answer in order make it  right and leaving a comment explaiing why i did that. Tell me if you fell that was the right choice or not but for me it was.