# Which projectiles and/or AoE's can be dodged by going invis?

Tags: dota-2

As a Templar Assassin, Bounty and Weaver player (among others), I'm never sure which projectiles I should be running/blinking away from, and which I could just dodge by becoming invisble. Furthemore, is there a rule as to which AoE spells hit invisible heroes? I know Kunkka's dreaded Tidebringer does, but are there any that don't?

As the full list must be long, is there a rule to tell which can be dodged so I can work it out in game ?

Something like *All auto attacks can be dodged by using invisibility* or *All magical projectiles can be dodged by going invisible e.g. Sven's stun*; or something more complex.

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I avoid damage from Sniper's Ultimate?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158626/how-can-i-avoid-damage-from-snipers-ultimate), if you need a full list, check the wiki : http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Disjoint#Projectile_abilities_that_cannot_be_disjointed

Comment: I know sniper's ulti can be dodged by going invis, cos I read the answer here, but for example I always tend to get hit by Sven's stun, which is also magical, so was looking for the full list, which has been provided below! :)

Comment: Agreed, even though the link for the disjoint page of the wiki is also given on the other answer, which might have answered your question ;D.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[List of abilities that you can disjoint by going invisible at the right moment](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Disjoint#Projectile_abilities_that_can_be_disjointed)

[List of abilities that you cannot disjoint by going invisible](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Disjoint#Projectile_abilities_that_cannot_be_disjointed)

[List of abilities that do not affect invisible units](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Invisibility#Area-of-effect_and_target-seeking_abilities_that_do_not_affect_invisible_units)

Every AoE spell that isn't listed on the 3rd link will affect invisible units (Tidebringer, Diabolic Edict, etc.)

Comment: You cann add Assassinate to the list of cannot be disjointed since the projectile grant true sight of the target and is thus not disjointable by becoming invis.

Comment: @WizLiz you're right there is already an asterisk on the wiki mentioning that

Comment: Could you use smoke to avoid since it isn't affected by true sight?

Comment: @ywm yes in theory. I'm not sure about the interaction of Smoke and Dust because I believe only sentries are supposed not to reveal Smoke (and gems carried by illusions I guess), but it should work with smoke too. You have to be outside the smoke detection range though